# Why does chrome driver has not x64 variant but edge driver does?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, selenium-edgedriver

They both are chromium based but only Edge has special driver for x64. Why?
[Chrome](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)
[Edge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/)

Answer (score 1):

Maintained by different orgs. Chrome -> Google, Edge -> Microsoft

64-bit version driver availability depends on browser implementation, priorities of the orgs etc. Microsoft took initiative to support 64-bit version of Edge browser, while Google prioritizes supporting 32-bit version because it is still widely used.

Chrome driver developers may also be considering other factors such as compatibility with other operating systems, the need to support multiple versions of the browser, and the availability of engineering resources.

But, it's highly likely a 64-bit version of Chrome driver will be available in the future.